# Navigation bar disappears when scrolling results from a search display controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a view with a search bar and a search display controller. It is the root view of a navigation controller. The search display controller acts as an autocomplete for the search bar.
The problem is the following:
I enter a letter in the search bar and the autocomplete results appear. I scroll down to the end of the results table view. After that I change my mind and type in another few letters until there are only 3 words in the table. I select a result in the table. In the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` I save the value that was selected and deactivate the search display controller using `setActive: FALSE animated: TRUE`. When it deactivates the navigation bar is missing. What did I do wrong?

Example: I type in `H`. A long list of keywords appear. I scroll down. I change my mind and type `OT` so the text in the search bar is now `HOT` there are approx. 6 keywords remaining, I select `HOTEL`. When I'm back the navigation bar is gone. I kill the app since it's useless. Next time I type in `HOT` ; without first scrolling down to see all the results, and after that I select `HOTEL`. This time it works, the navigation bar is still there.

EDIT: I think the problem appears when I have to scroll through the results if there is only one page of results it works ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813118/prevent-a-uisearchdisplaycontroller-from-hiding-the-navigation-bar/4005203#4005203) by using `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated: YES]`.