# UINavigationBar disappears iOS7

Tags: ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, viewwillappear

I have some wierd bug with UINavigationBar.

Sometimes it just disappears (actually if you move view to the half of screen, and then just release it)

[image: gif 5,3mb]

[Video example](http://youtu.be/hDRaiUFzmRQ)

In the first ViewController's `viewWillAppear:` method i call:

`[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];`

The second ViewController's `viewWillAppear:` contains:

`[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];`

I tried change `animated:` parameter, but it doesn't help.

Is it iOS7 bug or I just doing something wrong?

Comment: did u try self.navigationcontroller.navigationbarhidden = NO;?  Or do you have xib wihich contain no navigation bar? Setup xib file navigationbar type as transulent bnavigationbar.other than try to analyze the navigationbarhidden statements.

Comment: @NarasimhaiahKolli Yes, I tried this. It's the same as [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO].

Comment: @NarasimhaiahKolli and i have xib only just for first ViewController

Comment: you have to add transulent navigationbar to viewcontroller xib.just goto inspector properties of xib and add navigationbar to xib.

Comment: @NarasimhaiahKolli nothing changed. Navigation bar still disappears

Comment: Did you check this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813118/prevent-a-uisearchdisplaycontroller-from-hiding-the-navigation-bar

Comment: @NarasimhaiahKolli it's about UISearchDisplayController

Answer (score 2):

I found the reason for this.
That's happened because in `info.plist`

`View controller-based status bar appearance` is equal to `YES`

If change it to `NO`, then all will be fine

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, and fixed it.  the solution is:

1. Modify info.plist, set "View controller-based status bar appearance " to NO;
2. Delete all  - (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {}  ;
3. If your view controller has different status bar style, use [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

   e.g.  in viewWillAppear  set to light, in disappear ,set to dark style.

Answer (score 0):

You should define appearance per navigation controller.
If you want to have a navigation bar on the second controller only you should do the following in that particular controller:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

That way it will event work if you would need to change order of your controllers.

Comment: In this case Navigation Bar disappears before hiding ViewController, and on top I have black space.

Comment: Check that animated flag is set to `YES`. If I set that to `NO` I see the exact same thing as you described.

Comment: If i setNavigationBarHidden in viewWillDisappear of second controller it's the same as on gif. If i set it in viewWillDisappear of second and viewWillAppear of first, i have black space. Something like that