# Prevent UISearchController from hiding the navigation bar

Tags: ios, ios8

When a UISearchController's search bar becomes active, it hides the view's navigation bar. I'd like to have the search bar active below the navigation bar.

In iOS 7 there was a good way to do this for *UISearchDisplayController* here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12529945/3799720

But now in iOS 8 with UISearchController I can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This might have something to do with the UISearchController `hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation` property.

Comment: except that it doesn't work in some cases.  no really

Answer (score 2):

```
yourSearchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
```

this works in swift