# UISearchController without use of Navigation Controller

Tags: iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

Is it possible to use the `UISearchController` without the `SearchBar` being displayed in the `Navigation Controller`? I basically want the `SearchBar` to stay on the screen and display the TableView beneath it:

[image: Mockup]

What I was trying to do is this:
I've created a `UITableViewController` on the storyboard and linked it to the custom `NPTableViewController` class. Then I did this:

```
    let resultsTable = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LocationSearch") as! NPTableViewController
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsTable)
    searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = resultsTable

    let searchBar = searchController!.searchBar
    searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchBar.placeholder = "Search for places"
    searchBar.frame.origin.y = 100.0
    self.view.addSubview(searchBar)
```

Now when I run it, the `searchBar` is displayed but when I click on it the background dims, the `searchBar` disappears my `resultsTable` is also not displayed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30851467/implement-uisearchcontroller-with-uitableview/30851918#30851918

Comment: @Joe But how am I supposed to display the tableViewHeader without the TableView itself?

Comment: Nobody an idea?

Comment: [Prevent UISearchController from hiding the navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303495/prevent-uisearchcontroller-from-hiding-the-navigation-bar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution I came up with is actually very simple. Instead of using `UISearchController`, I used a normal `UISeachBar` and `UITableView`. Since `UISearchController` doesn't do so much to help you, the work is pretty much the same if I kind of build my own SearchController.

Comment: But adding a UISearchBar automatically adds a deprecated UISearchDisplayController which will crash your apps in production (didn't used to but does now). You may have to manually delete the UISearchDisplayController from any XIB or storyboard files.