# UISearchBar animates incorrectly underneath the navigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I have two view controllers each one contains `UISearchController` and a `UITableView`. The Code in `viewDidLoad` is:

```
SearchResultsTableViewController *searchResultController = [[SearchResultsTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SearchResultsTableViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navSearchResultsController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:searchResultController];

self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:navSearchResultsController];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = YES;
[self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.searchController.delegate = self;

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

The first view controller is the `rootViewController`, which works perfectly without any problem. The second view controller is being pushed via the navigation controller based on segment selection.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.vc];
```

There is only one problem with the second view controller. When I tap on the `searchBar`, it animates to the top and goes underneath the navigation bar while the first one animates in its spot and does not go up.

Can anyone tell me how to disable this animation?
I want to keep the `searchBar` in its same place while searching. It's exactly the same implementation for both view controllers. Why does each one act differently?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't understand this `the second view controller is being pushed via the navigation controller based on segment selection.`

Comment: I mean there is a segmented controller. When I tap on the second segment, it navigates to the second viewController.

Answer (score 0):

Set the [`hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation` boolean on the `UISearchController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchController/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISearchController/hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation) to `NO`.

```
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
```

Or try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12529945/1241782), it sounds similar to what you are trying to do. But you would probably want to adjust this line:

```
[super setActive: visible animated: animated]; // instead of passing animated, pass NO
```

Comment: I tried to set hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation and it does not work either. And the UISearchController does not have the animated parameter with the setActive method.